# Usability of a deeply discharged Li-ion batteries

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, capacity

I have a question about Li-ion batteries.

About three years back I bought two Sony VTC 5 batteries for my vape. They are rated as 2500 mAh 30 A.

But I quit smoking about a year ago and I left these batteries inside of my vaporizer. They were nearly discharged, so that was mistake number one I suppose, but I didn't give it a second thought at that time.

Recently I found that these batteries are still in the vape and I realised that I can use them in a project, because they are quite powerful and not that cheap to simply dispose of them and buy a pair of different ones. I measured them and they had only about 0.2 V, so I thought that they are dead. However I still tried to hook them up to a Li-ion charging module, which indeed recharged them to 4.15 V. I thought that maybe they'll undergo quick self discharge, as I've previously experienced with some old NiMH batteries. But they still do have 4.15 V and they are still powerful enough to run some high-current demanding applications.

But the unresolved question I still have is this: How has this over a year long deep discharge state influenced its capacity? I know that I cannot expect 2500 mAh, but I really don't have enough experience to make any sensible guess. I also don't possess any kind of a capacity meter, so a precise measurement of the actual value is not possible.

So do you have any kind of an estimate of the capacity left in the batteries? 75%? 50%? even less? You know, if there is still more than 1200 mAh, these batteries are more or less useful for me, but less than that is not worth it in the application I intend them to use in.

Comment: Be cautious, and near to the outdoors with a means to handle explosively flaming batteries. Very deeply disharged lithium batteries such as those that have at one point read 0.2V could be damaged and unsafe to use. I would look into their safety and reliability first before I looked into their remaining capacity.

Comment: Well, thats my concern too, I store them at home where I am not present for the majority of the week. Any idea how to test safety and realiability? Cycling them multiple times through full charge-full discharge (lets say to 2,8 V)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know the extent of the possible damages enough to tell you. I don't know if or how volatile they are after you have tested that they charged successfully.

Comment: Messure the capacitance and internal resistance. Compare with the datasheet. Done.

Comment: Are you sure these are bare cells, as opposed to ones with integrated protection circuitry? Could you add a photo?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not at home at this moment, but they look exactly like this: https://www.elementvape.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/o/sony_vtc5_18650_2600mah_30a_battery.jpg -  I would be really suprised if they managed to place any kind of protection circuitry inside. What do you think? 
Thanks for that idea of comparing datasheet values with measured ones, I'll give it a try :)